# Power ON/OFF a car using Arduino with IR remote control

Tags: c, arduino-uno

I posted this Question on [arduino.stackexchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39494/power-on-off-a-car-using-arduino-with-ir-remote-control), but i think this Question has to do (maybe) only with the language (C).

I have a car and I'm trying somehow to power OFF the car when a song plays using Arduino, with Infrared (IR) Remote. I decided to play a song (SuperMario) using a Buzzer and when I press the Power ON button works fine and the song plays.

The problem is when I press Power OFF, I have to wait until the song ends to Power off the car.

I was thinking that maybe I need threads or something, but I'm not sure, or maybe there is a better way to fix this.

Here is a Demo program:

```
#include "IRremote.h"

#define NOTE_B0  31
#define NOTE_C1  33
#define NOTE_CS1 35
#define NOTE_D1  37
#define NOTE_DS1 39
#define NOTE_E1  41
#define NOTE_F1  44
#define NOTE_FS1 46
#define NOTE_G1  49
#define NOTE_GS1 52
#define NOTE_A1  55
#define NOTE_AS1 58
#define NOTE_B1  62
#define NOTE_C2  65
#define NOTE_CS2 69
#define NOTE_D2  73
#define NOTE_DS2 78
#define NOTE_E2  82
#define NOTE_F2  87
#define NOTE_FS2 93
#define NOTE_G2  98
#define NOTE_GS2 104
#define NOTE_A2  110
#define NOTE_AS2 117
#define NOTE_B2  123
#define NOTE_C3  131
#define NOTE_CS3 139
#define NOTE_D3  147
#define NOTE_DS3 156
#define NOTE_E3  165
#define NOTE_F3  175
#define NOTE_FS3 185
#define NOTE_G3  196
#define NOTE_GS3 208
#define NOTE_A3  220
#define NOTE_AS3 233
#define NOTE_B3  247
#define NOTE_C4  262
#define NOTE_CS4 277
#define NOTE_D4  294
#define NOTE_DS4 311
#define NOTE_E4  330
#define NOTE_F4  349
#define NOTE_FS4 370
#define NOTE_G4  392
#define NOTE_GS4 415
#define NOTE_A4  440
#define NOTE_AS4 466
#define NOTE_B4  494
#define NOTE_C5  523
#define NOTE_CS5 554
#define NOTE_D5  587
#define NOTE_DS5 622
#define NOTE_E5  659
#define NOTE_F5  698
#define NOTE_FS5 740
#define NOTE_G5  784
#define NOTE_GS5 831
#define NOTE_A5  880
#define NOTE_AS5 932
#define NOTE_B5  988
#define NOTE_C6  1047
#define NOTE_CS6 1109
#define NOTE_D6  1175
#define NOTE_DS6 1245
#define NOTE_E6  1319
#define NOTE_F6  1397
#define NOTE_FS6 1480
#define NOTE_G6  1568
#define NOTE_GS6 1661
#define NOTE_A6  1760
#define NOTE_AS6 1865
#define NOTE_B6  1976
#define NOTE_C7  2093
#define NOTE_CS7 2217
#define NOTE_D7  2349
#define NOTE_DS7 2489
#define NOTE_E7  2637
#define NOTE_F7  2794
#define NOTE_FS7 2960
#define NOTE_G7  3136
#define NOTE_GS7 3322
#define NOTE_A7  3520
#define NOTE_AS7 3729
#define NOTE_B7  3951
#define NOTE_C8  4186
#define NOTE_CS8 4435
#define NOTE_D8  4699
#define NOTE_DS8 4978

#define powerLedRed    2
#define powerLedGreen  3
#define receiver       5
#define buzzer         7

void translateIR( void );
void powerON( void );;
void powerOFF( void );
void swap( int *x, int *y );
void playSuperMario( void );
void buzz( int targetPin, long frequency, long length );

int power           = 2;
int switchOFF       = 0;
int switchON        = 1;

int melody[] = {
  NOTE_E7, NOTE_E7, 0, NOTE_E7,  0, NOTE_C7, NOTE_E7, 0,
  NOTE_G7, 0, 0,  0,  NOTE_G6, 0, 0, 0,
  NOTE_C7, 0, 0, NOTE_G6,  0, 0, NOTE_E6, 0, 0,
  NOTE_A6, 0, NOTE_B6,  0, NOTE_AS6, NOTE_A6, 0,
  NOTE_G6, NOTE_E7, NOTE_G7,  NOTE_A7, 0, NOTE_F7, NOTE_G7, 0,
  NOTE_E7, 0, NOTE_C7,  NOTE_D7, NOTE_B6, 0, 0,
  NOTE_C7, 0, 0, NOTE_G6,  0, 0, NOTE_E6, 0, 0,
  NOTE_A6, 0, NOTE_B6,  0, NOTE_AS6, NOTE_A6, 0,
  NOTE_G6, NOTE_E7, NOTE_G7,  NOTE_A7, 0, NOTE_F7, NOTE_G7, 0,
  NOTE_E7, 0, NOTE_C7,  NOTE_D7, NOTE_B6, 0, 0
};

int tempo[] = {
  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12,
  9, 9, 9,  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12,
  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12,
  9, 9, 9,  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12,
};

int underworld_melody[] = {
  NOTE_C4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4,  NOTE_AS3, NOTE_AS4, 0,  0,
  NOTE_C4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4,  NOTE_AS3, NOTE_AS4, 0,  0,
  NOTE_F3, NOTE_F4, NOTE_D3, NOTE_D4,  NOTE_DS3, NOTE_DS4, 0,  0,
  NOTE_F3, NOTE_F4, NOTE_D3, NOTE_D4,  NOTE_DS3, NOTE_DS4, 0,  0,
  NOTE_DS4, NOTE_CS4, NOTE_D4, NOTE_CS4, NOTE_DS4, NOTE_DS4, NOTE_GS3,
  NOTE_G3, NOTE_CS4, NOTE_C4, NOTE_FS4, NOTE_F4, NOTE_E3, NOTE_AS4, NOTE_A4,
  NOTE_GS4, NOTE_DS4, NOTE_B3, NOTE_AS3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_GS3, 0, 0, 0
};

int underworld_tempo[] = {
  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 6,  3,
  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 6,  3,
  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 6,  3,
  12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 6,
  6, 18, 18, 18,  6, 6,  6, 6,  6, 6,
  18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18,  10, 10, 10,
  10, 10, 10, 3, 3, 3
};

IRrecv irrecv(receiver);
decode_results results;

void setup( void )
{
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(powerLedGreen, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(powerLedRed,   OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("IR Receiver Button Decode");
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
}

void loop( void )
{
  if ( power == 2 ) {
    powerOFF();
  }

  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    translateIR();
    irrecv.resume();
  }
}

void playSuperMario( void ) {
  Serial.println(" 'Mario Theme'");
  int size = sizeof(melody) / sizeof(int);
  for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < size; thisNote++) {
    int noteDuration = 1000 / tempo[thisNote];
    buzz(buzzer, melody[thisNote], noteDuration);

    int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;
    delay(pauseBetweenNotes);

    buzz(buzzer, 0, noteDuration);
  }
}

void buzz( int targetPin, long frequency, long length ) {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  long delayValue = 1000000 / frequency / 2; // calculate the delay value between transitions
  long numCycles = frequency * length / 1000; // calculate the number of cycles for proper timing

  for (long i = 0; i < numCycles; i++) { // for the calculated length of time...
    digitalWrite(targetPin, HIGH); // write the buzzer pin high to push out the diaphram
    delayMicroseconds(delayValue); // wait for the calculated delay value
    digitalWrite(targetPin, LOW); // write the buzzer pin low to pull back the diaphram
    delayMicroseconds(delayValue); // wait again or the calculated delay value
  }

  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}

void translateIR( void ) {
  switch (results.value) {
    case 0xFF02FD:
      Serial.println(" -OK-");

      swap(&switchON, &switchOFF);

      if (switchON == 0 )
      {
        powerON();
        playSuperMario();
      }
      else
      {
        powerOFF();
      }
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println(" other button   ");
      power = 0;
  }
  //delay(500);
}

void powerOFF( void ) {
  digitalWrite(powerLedRed,   HIGH);
  digitalWrite(powerLedGreen, LOW);
  power = 0;
}

void powerON( void ) {
  digitalWrite(powerLedRed,   LOW);
  digitalWrite(powerLedGreen, HIGH);
}

void swap( int *x, int *y ) {
  if (*x != *y) {
    *x ^= *y;
    *y ^= *x;
    *x ^= *y;
  }
}
```

inside the `translateIR` function I have this:

```
void translateIR( void ) {
  switch (results.value) {
    case 0xFF02FD:
      Serial.println(" -OK-");

      swap(&switchON, &switchOFF);

      if (switchON == 0 )
      {
        powerON();
        playSuperMario();
      }
      else
      {
        powerOFF();
      }
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println(" other button   ");
      power = 0;
  }
  //delay(500);
}
```

Here, are called both functions, `powerON()` and `playSuperMario();` so I need somehow to power OFF the car during the Song is played.

Here is a [VIDEO Demo](https://youtu.be/DZtzMjYlNBA).
How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget threads, this is a microcontroller we're talking about here.  I'd suggest a timer-based interrupt that fires perhaps once every 100 milliseconds or so.  Short time for a human ear but lots of time between interrupts for a micro executing 16 million instructions per second.  So, in the interrupt you check if button has been pressed.  If it has, set a variable that is checked in the main loop and if set, turns the melody off.

Maximum latency = 100 ms plus a few clock cycles.

I'm not going to write the code for you.  But I'll tell you what to google for.  You first need to read the datasheet for the microcontroller that's on your particular Arduino board.  Download that from Atmel.  Then study up on how to set up a timer in CTC mode, how to set the prescaler, how to code an interrupt for it in the compiler-IDE of your choice, how to detect a button press during the interrupt, how to set a `volatile` variable in the interrupt body, and how to check that variable in the main loop and interrupt the melody.  Lots to learn in embedded programming and it's all out there on the internet.  Start with the datasheet.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to rewrite your program to make it multi-threaded as that's behind the scope of answering a specific question. I can give you a description of what's required though as a starting point.

First of all, a simpler way to fix this without threads would be to use something like [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) to stop the playing of the tune. This is what happens when you press Ctrl-C. Your program is reading input from your IR though, so as far as I can tell using threads looks necessary to both reading IR input and playing of sound happen at the same time.

I'm not familiar with Arduino but I'm assuming you have something like [pthreads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads). You would need to get familiar with that. It is not a trivial change as using threads is very different paradigm and takes time to get your head around if you haven't used them before. The main thing to get your head around is that code is executing in more than one place.

Your main thread, the beginning process before any thread is created, would be running `loop()` so it can respond to any IR input. Having it in its own thread lets it respond to any user input. The problem with your code right is that it must wait for the playing of the tune in `playSuperMario()` to return before it can process any new input.

You would create a thread somewhere during initialization. This thread will be what plays the tune. It needs to be able to start the tune based on IR input. Also you'll need to define the behavior of things like what happens if the "ON" button is pressed while it's already playing? Does it start again, stop or is that ignored and it keeps playing?

You'll need one or more variables used by both threads. This will require **mutex** protection so only one thread can read/write it at a time. Let's say there's a global variable `isPlaying` initially set to `true`. When the off button is pressed this would be changed to `false`. Your `playSuperMario()` and `buzz()`, etc. functions would need to check if this value is false in its loops. If false then it will return immediately.

That's a general pointer to how to handle this hope it helps.

Comment: The arduino doesn't have pthreads - It does have a very much simpler thread implementation of protothreads. The best approach is probably not to look into threads (that really isn't needed here), but rather play the music in a timer ISR.